# JSON.stringify returns different values for dates

Tags: javascript, json, date

i'm needing my json.stringify method to return me something like this:

```
//The code below is the same as JSON.stringify(new Date());
console.log(new Date().toJSON());
```

This returns me the following:

```
"/Date(1373046760480-0300)/"
```

which is fine, but it happens in certain scenarios that the same operation returns me this:

```
"2013-07-05T17:52:55.434Z"
```

which is not the expected result, and then i have to create string to have the expected result.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: What circumstances? As far as I can tell, it always returns the latter string.

Comment: ??? In what scenario in what browser do you ever get the first string?

Comment: For me console.log(new Date().toJSON()) returns "2013-07-05T18:05:10.600Z" in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: The first is not valid JSON.

Comment: @Barmar: Neither is the 2nd one.  What's your point?

Comment: According to the specification, `toJSON` should call `toISOString` (http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.44).

Comment: seams that `JSON.stringify(new Date())` does not return the same: http://jsbin.com/ujacot/2/edit

Comment: @intuitivepixel: Yes they do.  `stringify` justs adds quotes, so that it's JSON, `toJSON` just gives a string.

Comment: I'm using sencha, perhaps sencha is the responsible for this behaviour... i was just thinking that they may be different types of dates and never noticed :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless someone accidentally (by using third party library) overwrites `Date.prototype.toJSON` the default output of JSON date is the latter:

Here's what could be (a non-standard implementation used by asp.net)

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function(){ return "/Date(" + this.getTime() + ")/" }
```

Comment: That is the case, the sencha framework does this... thanks i started thinking my knowledge of dates in js was rusty!